# Dart TCP calls not getting any response

Tags: dart, tcp, tcpclient

I am recreating some JavaScript code in Dart.

The code creates a connection to a smart device using TCP, sends data and listens to a response.

JavaScript code

```
var socket = net.connect(port, ip);
socket.write(Buffer.from(data, 'hex'));
socket.once('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

My Dart code

```
/// Creating a socket with the device ip and port
Socket socket = await Socket.connect(ip, port);          

/// Send data to the device
socket.write(data);

/// Getting first response synchronicly
Uint8List dataFromDevice = await socket.first;

print(dataFromDevice);
```

For some reason I am never getting any response from the smart device.

There is no error and the socket object has connected attribute.
I am suspicious that the data is not being sent at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that by changing the `socket.write(data);` to `socket.add(data);`.

Fixed code

```
/// Creating a socket with the device ip and port
Socket socket = await Socket.connect(ip, port);          

/// Send data to the device
socket.add(data);

/// Getting first response synchronicly
Uint8List dataFromDevice = await socket.first;

print(dataFromDevice);
```

I have **hypotheses** as to why this works.

`.write` in dart don't know how to handle array of bites like the JavaScript `.write` do.

So for transferring List of bytes we use the `.add` function.

Comment: Correct. `.write` is documented as "Converts object to a String by invoking Object.toString and adds the encoding of the result to the target consumer.". So it calls `.toString()`, converts this string into bytes and then sends them. This is not the same as adding all elements of the list to the socket. :)